# Replacing and search hexadecimals in a line in python

Tags: python, search, replace, hex

The problem is as follows:
I'm doing a file.read(100) and getting something like a line as follows:

```
line='1\x01\x1e17=00000000\x1e54=80300A00\x1e50=1\x1e56=2008080106010414\x1c\x1e247=CD\x1e6=In\x1e5=Boot\x1e180=0.445\x1e179=0.380\x1e55=AAA\x1e57=2008080100000000\x1e212=5000\x1e213=20000\x1e115=500\x1d\x1e29=5T2lqZHNAwg=\x01\x1e17=00000000'
```

What I want to do is search this line for the hexadecimal numbers and convert them to output the newly manipulated line.
So essentially I'd want to do:

```
t=re.findall(r'[\x80-\xff]', line) #Somehow get the positions    
for i in t: ord(i) #Something to this effect to replace all the hexadecimals it finds
```

Using the code I have for t, I don't find all the characters in the line let alone their positions.
I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts on how best to approach this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to back up a step and ask if that input makes sense. It looks to me like you're trying to read the file with an incorrect encoding.

Comment: The file is a .dat.gz Reading it in UNIX there are a lot of special characters like ^^ etc... The only way I know of reading it is simply using gzip and doing a read. You have any further thoughts on the encoding?

Comment: You're looking for characters in the range `\x80-\xff` but the characters in your string are in the range `\x01-\x1f`. I'm not sure how the regular expression parser will handle those but it's a place to start.

Comment: @FancyDolphin read kreativitea's answer. That's a better explanation of what I'm talking about. All I know about encoding issues is that I don't know anything about encoding issues.

Answer (score 1):

`\x` is an escaped x, which is an invalid escape.  Your issue isn't the regex, it's your encoding-- your `line` isn't a literal string.  Try `print`ing `line`, you should see the following:

```
117=0000000054=80300A0050=156=2008080106010414247=CD6=In5=Boot180=0.445179=0.38055=AAA57=2008080100000000212=5000213=20000115=50029=5T2lqZHNAwg=17=00000000
```

Likely, this is what you need.  In short, the hex values are fine just the way they are.

If after this, you still want to get the hex values, you have to add an `r` to the beginning of the string like so:

```
line=r'1\x01\x1e17=00000000\x1e54=80300A00\x1e50=1\x1e56=2008080106010414\x1c\x1e247=CD\x1e6=In\x1e5=Boot\x1e180=0.445\x1e179=0.380\x1e55=AAA\x1e57=2008080100000000\x1e212=5000\x1e213=20000\x1e115=500\x1d\x1e29=5T2lqZHNAwg=\x01\x1e17=00000000'
```

To make it a string literal.  Regex should work over the literal just like any other string.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the indices of the characters `\x` (as well as [0] and [len(t) - 1], then iterate through that list and slice through in pairs of two, as in `ord(t[i:i+1])` for i in len(t)

Comment: My experience has been running searches and indices of the character('\x') gives a ValueError: invalid \x escape. I think if I can get a list of all the Hex in the line then I can just search for item in the list and replace the line. However, the problem is that python isn't finding those Hex's correctly.

Comment: Aha, the backslash character is an escape: to make a string `"\x"`, you want to let `s = "\\x"`

Comment: @nair.ashvin While that certainly is a problem he will have to deal with, that's not the problem he currently has.

Comment: Agreed, unless he actually does want to search through the original  string literal.